# Joining 8 strings to form 1 string in C

Tags: c, string, strcpy, strcat

I am doing a `C` programming school project. In one part of the project, I need to join every 8 strings (each 4 characters in length) to form 1 string (each 32 characters in length).

For example, `char *holdBinary[16]` holds 16 strings such as:

```
holdBinary[0] = "0000";
holdBinary[1] = "0000";
holdBinary[2] = "0000";
holdBinary[3] = "0000";
holdBinary[4] = "0000";
holdBinary[5] = "0000";
holdBinary[6] = "0000";
holdBinary[7] = "0000";
holdBinary[8] = "0000";
holdBinary[9] = "0000";
holdBinary[10] = "0010";
holdBinary[11] = "1010";
holdBinary[12] = "0000";
holdBinary[13] = "0000";
holdBinary[14] = "0000";
holdBinary[15] = "0000";
```

I need to join every 8 strings in `holdBinary` to form 1 string which is held in `holdRange` char array. Thus, the results: `holdeRange[0] = "00000000000000000000000000000000"` which is formed by `holdBinary[0]`, `holdBinary[1]` .... `holdBinary[7]` and `holdeRange[1] = "00000000001010100000000000000000"`.

Here is the code:

```
char holdRange[2][33];  // I changed here and it works correct now


int hold = 0;
int z = 0;
int index2 = -1;

while(z<16)
{
    if(z%8 == 0)
    {

        index2++;
        strcpy(holdRange[index2] , holdBinary[z]);
    }
    else
    {

        strcat(holdRange[index2] , holdBinary[z]);
    }
    z++;

}
printf("%s" , holdRange[0]); --> prints 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000001010100000000000000000
printf("\n");
printf("%s" , holdRange[1]); --> prints 00000000001010100000000000000000
```

Thus, `holdRange[0]` is not equal to what must be. How can I fix it?

Comment: `char holdRange[32];` or am I missing something?

Comment: holdRange should hold 6 strings which have length 32. numberOfChar/8 states that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Missing the trailing NULL? `char holdRange[33];`

Comment: "Please help me , time is limited" - oh no! Will the world end?

Comment: I did not understand what you wanted to say. As I mentioned , holdRange array should be defined to hold 6 strings which every string has 32 length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using %s to `printf` something generally requires a `\0` character at the end, which you did not leave room for in your string -- it needs to hold 33 characters if you want 32 "real" characters and a null terminator.

Comment: Okey I have fixed it but same problem still arises:/

Comment: Did you try to make both fixes (ie this one and @Karolis) at the same time?  That probably won't work. Can you show us what the code looks like now?

Comment: I have only changed char (*holdRange)[33] , code did not change and still does not work.

Comment: I have copied the code above, changed the 32 to 33 and removed the cast of malloc which you shouldn't have anyway, and got the result wanted -- two lines of sixteen (-- EDIT thirty-two what am I saying --) characters each.  If that's not what you're getting, then recheck what you have with what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate one block of memory for two strings. I assume that's because you confused yourself with the odd types you use. All you need is `char* holdRange[2]` and memory for each of the strings.

Sure, it could be made to work your way, but you're not thinking of `\0` either.

Comment: But this `char *holdRange[2]` won't be an array of strings; it would be an array of pointers which point to non-contiguous pieces of memory, which may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: It did not solve the problem. Now it shows holdRange[0] =0000000000001010100000000000000000 and holdRange[1] = 00000000001010100000000000000000. Please helppp!!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out 32 characters and wants the characters stored in contiguous memory, give a format specifier to `printf()`:

```
printf("%.32s" , holdRange[0]);
printf("\n");
printf("%.32s" , holdRange[1]);
```

Comment: But it does not change anything , holdRange[0] and holdRange[1] does not hold right value.

Comment: Did you change your initial implementation?

Comment: Okey I have fixed the problem I am posting the answer.